# Use a var returned by a script within a subsequent php passage

Tags: javascript, php, dom

Presently,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get("http://[somewebsite]", function (response) {
       $("#somevalue").html(response.somevalue);
    }, "jsonp");
</script>
```

up in the body of the source returns a `somevalue` variable that is then used like this within the page:

```
<div id="somevalue"></div>
```

and the underlying value is successfully printed out.  But down below further in the source I have some PHP coding that I would like to employ that variable in.  If in that later PHP coding I want to take `<div id="somevalue"></div>` (merely writing `somevalue` just outputs string literal "somevalue" in the html), and assign the value to `n` for use inside the PHP, how is such an instruction written?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load that PHP part later via an Ajax request as well. In this way you can pass the 'somevalue' as a parameter (GET or POST) and you can process it on the server-side.

```
$.get("http://[somewebsite]", function (response) {
    $("#somevalue").html(response.somevalue);
    loadSomething(response.somevalue);
}, "jsonp");


function loadSomething(somevalue) {
    $.get('/later.php', { n: somevalue }, function(response) {
        // Inject the response into the DOM or do something else
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is informative. I will pursue this solution.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: On re-reading your question, I'm thinking you actually wanted to use the value as a variable in PHP? That can't be easily done unfortunately, as PHP is handled on the server, before the JavaScript is executed. You could try using the `cURL` functions to get the value you want independently of your AJAX?

---

It's a little hacky, but you could try replacing your top part with this:

```
var outputHTML = '';
$.get("http://[somewebsite]", function (response) {
   outputHTML = response.somevalue;
   $("#somevalue").html(outputHTML);
   $(".somevalue-later").html(outputHTML);
}, "jsonp");
```

And then when you want to use it later, use this:

```
<?php
echo("Blah blah blah <span class=\"somevalue-later\"></span> blah blah");
?>
```

That should all work, but as stated at the top I suspect that's not what you were looking for in the first place anyway. If you can expand on your question I'm sure I or others will be able to help you.

Comment: That won't work. The second script will run before the Ajax callback.

Comment: @Paulpro You're right, I missed that. Too much late-night coding! I'll update to a fixed version...

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm trying your last statement and it's drawing a PHP parsing error.

Comment: @ni37osllb There were errors in the first version. Try the code I put up just now :)

Comment: On UPDATE: Your first reading was correct. I actually do need to use a variable returned up in the client script on the .php page source again down below in the server-side PHP encoding. Thanks also for the cURL info.